# no kex aleg issues on SSH for Windows

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I installed OpenSSH on Windows. However, I'm getting **no keg alg** issues when trying to connect to my Amazon EC2 instance. I can connect it through WinSCP and Putty using the same identity file. I also added the KexAlgorithms config in my etc/sshd_config file.

[image]

**etc/sshd_config**

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't completely agree. The Help centre also says that if your question generally covers software tools commonly used by programmers, then you are in the right place.

Comment: I solved this by connecting through git-bash... No clue on the missing algorithms...

Comment: @PaulMelero , Could you put there your full command  ? thanks.

Comment: @FeigaLubow for me it wasn't the specific command. Just by running the same commands on git bash (in Windows), the problem went away ‍♂️

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. And the problem was that my ssh client was outdated.

You can solve by downloading the latest binaries: [OpenSSH Binaries Windows](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases)

Just extract the zip file and add the folder into your environment variables and you won't see that problem anymore :)

Comment: Can you explain how to add the folder into the environment variables?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was with the windows version ,
my machien was windows 2012 and its not supported the ssh .
I tried to connect from windows 2019 machine and it work!