# "Bad configuration option: KexAlgorithms"

Tags: windows, ssh, openssh

I am trying to ssh into a remote server for my university on a Windows 10 computer.

I installed OpenSSH. When I first tried to ssh in, I would get the error

```
no kex alg
```

Doing some googling, I put the following in my /.ssh/config file

```
  KexAlgorithms kexalgorithms curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
```

However, now when I try to ssh, I get these errors:

```
/cygdrive/c/Users/name/.ssh/config: line 3: Bad configuration option: KexAlgorithms
```

`/cygdrive/c/Users/name/.ssh/config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options`

I'm new to trying this and have been frustrated for hours. Anyone know how I can fix this? Thank you :)

UPDATE: Changed my config file to this based off comment, still getting error:

```
Host name@remote_server
  HostName name@remote_server
  KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
```

Error message still the same, still getting error with line 3, KeyAlgorithmns

Comment: Try changing `KexAlgorithms kexalgorithms` to `KexAlgorithms`.

Comment: Changed it and still getting the same error.

Comment: Change `KexAlgorithms` to `HostKeyAlgorithms`.

Answer (score 0):

The binaries of ssh in windows 10 are outdated. You should download the new ssh binaries and add them to the windows environment variables and it's fixed. [Stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57136371/4051258)